# Combine set of list variables into a dataframe, using a list which references those list variables

Tags: r

This was difficult to articulate, so have created an example. I have a set of list variables which I'd like to combine into a dataframe. These are examples of the lists

```
a <-  2:7
b <- 9:14
c <- 25:30
d <- 31:36
```

I have a list which has items that references the above list names

```
vars <- c("a","b","c","d")
```

I would like a way to combine those lists using an instruction on "vars <- c("a","b","c","d")". Is there a kind of data.frame(get(vars)) instruction that will join all those list items into a dataframe?
The result would look like this

```
df_result <- data.frame(a= 2:7, b = 9:14, c = 25:30, d = 31:36 )
> df_result
  a  b  c  d
1 2  9 25 31
2 3 10 26 32
3 4 11 27 33
4 5 12 28 34
5 6 13 29 35
6 7 14 30 36
```

Maybe it can't be done with one instruction, if there is any workarounds that would be great too.
Any help greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of `mget` you could do:

```r
a <-  2:7
b <- 9:14
c <- 25:30
d <- 31:36

vars <- c("a","b","c","d")


d <- mget(vars, env = globalenv())
d <- do.call("cbind", d)
data.frame(d)
#>   a  b  c  d
#> 1 2  9 25 31
#> 2 3 10 26 32
#> 3 4 11 27 33
#> 4 5 12 28 34
#> 5 6 13 29 35
#> 6 7 14 30 36
```